# Invalid Field Definition

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a table with a foreign key using `SQL` command but I keep getting this error

`Invalid field definition 'CUS_CODE' in definition of index or relationship.`

I'm using this command:

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE(
INV_NUMBER      CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
INV_DATE        DateTime    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT      INV_PK      PRIMARY KEY(INV_NUMBER),
CONSTRAINT      INV_FK      FOREIGN KEY(CUS_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUS_CODE)
);
```

Comment: Cus_code is not a field in your invoice table. `FOREIGN KEY(You column name in your invoice table) REFERENCES Customer(Cus_Code)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `Cus_code` is not a field in your invoice table.

It should be :

```
FOREIGN KEY(Your column name in your invoice table) REFERENCES Customer(Cus_Code)
```

[Here's an tutorial about SQL FOREIGN KEY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

It should help you to illustrate what it should looks like

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  I was under assumption that the constraint statement would automatically create the column.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. So you gonna have to add a column `cus_code` in your invoice table. Glad to help

Comment: While we're on the subject why does this line cause SYNTAX Error:  LINE_UNITS  NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL  I'm trying to create a numeric field and when I run that line it comes back with syntax error.  If I change it to CHAR it works fine.

Comment: So people can find the answer if they have the same problem, you should make another question

Comment: @Nick I need your database system

Comment: To be more specific it throws syntax error if I add parameter to numeric.  If I do it without parameter it works fine.  DB is Access.

Comment: i think I know why, can you make another question plz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733788/syntax-error-when-creating-numeric-column