# Syntax Error when creating Numeric column

Tags: sql, ms-access

Syntax error getting thrown when passing parameter to NUMERIC(4).  If its passes as just NUMERIC it works fine.  DB used is Access.

```
CREATE TABLE LINE(
INV_NUMBER      CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
LINE_NUMBER     CHAR(1)     NOT NULL,
P_CODE          VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
LINE_UNITS      NUMERIC(4)  NOT NULL,
LINE_PRICE      CURRENCY    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT      LIN_PK      PRIMARY KEY(LINE_NUMBER),
CONSTRAINT      LIN_FK      FOREIGN KEY(INV_NUMBER) REFERENCES INVOICE(INV_NUMBER)
);
```

Comment: To answer this, please provide your sql db vendor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here, you can find all access data types](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp)
and `NUMERIC` is not supported, you have to use `INTEGER`

Answer (score 3):

Access doesn't have a `NUMERIC` data type.  Use `INTEGER` instead.

See valid data types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208866%28v=office.12%29.aspx).