# Create Table constraint broken

Tags: sql, ms-access, create-table

I have a program that creates a Microsoft access database then fills it with tables, most of the tables have primary/foreign key relationships and I'm trying to use this SQL to create one of the tables however I get a syntax error in constraint error when I try to run it, it happens at the first "FOREIGN KEY".

```
CREATE TABLE TblClass (ClassID Text, StudentID Integer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TblStudent(StudentID), TeacherID Integer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TblTeacher(TeacherID));
```

I found this syntax on the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) website as I found the Microsoft documentation on constraints confusing. I get the same error if I run the code in my program or if I run it in a query within the database. I have already used sql to create the tblteacher with the teacherID counter and tblstudent with the studentID counter.

Comment: is it possible TblStudent doesnt exists? 
what is the error that you get?

Comment: The TblStudent and TblTeacher are created before the TblClass, both are created with no errors, I confirmed it in the actual database file. the sql gives me the error "Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause." for the TblClass statement then it highlights the first "FOREIGN" in the statement

Comment: @DanielRapaport sorry I probably should have tagged you in my comment

Answer (score 0):

I needed to define the studentID and teacherID before the constraint such as in the following

```
CREATE TABLE TblClass (ClassID Text, StudentID Integer, TeacherID Integer, CONSTRAINT FK_StudentID FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES TblStudent(StudentID), CONSTRAINT FK_TeacherID FOREIGN KEY (TeacherID) REFERENCES TblTeacher(TeacherID));
```

now the code works fine.

Comment: I found this answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732567/invalid-field-definition)